Problem with AutoMapper in ABP Can not map from given object
I am developing an ABP application with .net core 8.
I have an entity Member as
 public class Member: AuditedAggregateRoot<Guid>
 {
     public string MembershipNo { get; set; }
     public string EmployeeNo { get; set; }
     public string FirstName { get; set; }
     public string MiddleName { get; set; }
     public string LastName { get; set; }
     public string Gender { get; set; }
     public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
     public DateTime EmploymentDate { get; set; }
     public string TelephoneNo { get; set; }
     public string PhyisicalAddress { get; set; }
     public string PostalAddress { get; set; }
     public string EmailAddress { get; set; }

 }

and I I have created DTO for this object as follows
public class MemberDto : AuditedEntityDto<Guid>
{
    public string MembershipNo { get; set; }
    public string EmployeeNo { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string MiddleName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Gender { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
    public DateTime EmploymentDate { get; set; }
    public string TelephoneNo { get; set; }
    public string PhyisicalAddress { get; set; }
    public string PostalAddress { get; set; }
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }

}

I have created an autoMapper profile as follos
public class AbpTestAutoMapperProfile : Profile
{
    public AbpTestAutoMapperProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<MemberDto, Member>().IgnoreAuditedObjectProperties() ;
        CreateMap<Member, MemberDto>().IgnoreAuditedObjectProperties();//.ForMember(dest => dest.Name, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => $"{src.FirstName} {src.MiddleName} {src.LastName}-({src.EmployeeNo})"));
        CreateMap<MemberDto, CreateUpdateMemberDto>();
        CreateMap<CreateUpdateMemberDto, Member>().IgnoreAuditedObjectProperties();
    }
}

I have configured autoMapper as follows
Configure<AbpAutoMapperOptions>(options =>
{
    options.AddMaps<AppModule>();
    options.AddProfile<AbpTestAutoMapperProfile>();
});

But when I try to evaluate the mapping
var member = await _memberRepository.GetAsync(id);

var mbm = ObjectMapper.Map<Member, MemberDto>(member);

I get an error :
Can not map from given object ([ENTITY: MemberProxy] Id = 95a81b14-c881-4d59-5fcb-3a12b307b806) to AbpTest.Contracts.MemberDto, AbpTest, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null.
The version of automapper is Volo.Abp.AutoMapper" Version="8.2.2
What might be the reason for this Error.
Regards

Try by removing IgnoreAuditedObjectProperties() once

I am assuming in the module "where you have configured automapper", you just need to decorate your class with [DependsOn(typeof(AbpAutoMapperModule))].
